# Rust From trait abuse?

Tags: rust, traits

Let's say I have an **object** struct that I want to create **From** **config** struct, that seems reasonable - that is a conversion from one struct type to another.

Then let's say that I want to create the latter **config** struct from [Path](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html)?

Meaning from trait implementation taking Path as the parameter, opening the YAML file, parsing it, and returning the **config** struct.

How much abuse will that be, or will it be a completely normal and acceptable thing to do?

I've definitely seen the first usage case of traits in the oss code, but haven't seen the latter one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Meaning from trait implementation taking Path as the parameter, opening yaml file, parsing it, and returning config struct.
>
> How much of an abuse will that be, or will it be completely normal and acceptable thing to do?

It's a significant abuse:

1. The entire process is rife with points of failure, but `From` is *non-failable*.
2. `From` and `TryFrom` are both designed for *conversions*. Your use-case has nothing to do with conversion, you can't call that converting a path to a configuration object without making the term *completely meaningless*.

And at a fundamental level... it doesn't really make sense? The point of `From`/`TryFrom` is to serve as generic bounds so that e.g. a function can take anything which is convertible to / from a concrete type it knows. How useful is an `Into<Config>` bound going to be? I'm guessing "not very".

Comment: A more natural approach would be to implement some sort of constructor for `Config`, e.g. `fn from_file(file: AsRef<Path>) -> Result<Error, Self> { ... }`.